# How to connect two circles on the same plane via tangent with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Given two circles on the same plane, how can I add a line which connects both circles on the tangent (so this would often be two lines)?

[image]

If I have these two black circles, I want to have the yellow line (which should end at the tangent points of the circles).

Comment: How they are defined? Object centers and radii, or they are just meshes?

Comment: Objects centers, sorry for that less info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on where exactly you want to go..

[image]

... this might seem a good GN starting-point

Comment: Damn, that’s great!!!

Comment: that's already more than i wanted, thank you!!! i will now make my connection rod automatically with geometry nodes ;) just two empties given GN will do the rest for me ;)

Answer (score 8):

Geometry answer.

Subtract one radius from the other and make a line between the new radius and the center point of the other. Then offset the line by the subtracted value:

[image]

The line between the point and circle is easy to get, because the tangent makes a 90° angle to the center of the circle, so you can use the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) to find all pieces:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you Crantisz +1 - really great answer!

Comment: What do you mean by *"offset the line on the subtracted value"*? Do you mean *"offset the line* ***by*** *the subtracted value"*? Or something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yep, thanks