# Connect multiple circles by chosen shared tangent lines in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

Picture 1 shows an example of 3 circles combined through a convex hull node. All circles are connected by their shared tangent lines. Picture two shows what I'm trying to achieve, an additional circle that is connected by the OTHER shared tangent line of a circle, making use of the circle's negative space. How could this be achieved with Geometry Nodes?
[image: 3 circles combined in a convex hull]

[image: a fourth circle added, connected by an alternative shared tangent]

The node tree should be able to:
-produce a single manifold geometry
-switch between tangent lines based on the angle of the corresponding circles
-produce a mesh using any number of circles

User Crantisz provides a good way to use nodes to produce a line between any two given circles in [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265052/how-to-connect-two-circles-on-the-same-plane-via-tangent-with-geometry-nodes?newreg=bb9a02d8f62b4087a409808625cb46ac) but I can't seem to adapt it to my use.